# Scrape a page when URL does not change with page number - R

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I want to scrape all the URLs from this page:

http://www.domainia.nl/QuarantaineList.aspx

I am able to scrape the first page, however, I can not change the page, because it is not in the URL. So how can I change the page with scraping? I've been looking into RSelenium, but could not get it working.

I'm running the next code to get at least the first page:

```
#Constructin the to scrape urls
baseURL <- "http://www.domainia.nl/quarantaine/"
date <- gsub("-", "/", Sys.Date())
URL <- paste0(baseURL, date)

#Scraping the page
page <- read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes("td") %>% html_text()
links <- str_subset(page, pattern = "^\r\n.*.nl$")
links <- gsub(pattern = "\r\n", "", links) %>% trimws
```

Comment: This turned out to be easier than expected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795664/unexpected-symbol-in-copying-a-curl-r/53796309#53796309

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the site; it's using a Javascript POST to refresh its contents.
Originally a HTTP-POST was meant to send information to a server, for example to send the contents of what somebody entered in a form. As such, it often includes information on the page you are coming from, which means you probably will need more information then just "page n".

If you want to get another page, like your browser would show you, you need to send a similar request. The `httr` package inlcudes a `POST` function, I think you should take a look at that.
For knowing what to post, I think it's most useful to capture what your browser does, and copy that. In Chrome, you can use inspect, tab Network to see what is sent and received, I bet other browsers have similar tools.

However, it looks like that website makes its money by showing that information, and if some other source would show the same things, they'd lose money. Therefore I doubt if it's that easy to emulate, I think some part of the request differs every time, yet needs to be exactly right. For example, they could build checks to see if the entire page was rendered, instead of discarded like you do. So I wouldn't be surprised if they intentionally make it very hard to do what you are trying to do.

Which brings me to an entirely different solution: ask them!
When I tried scraping a website with dynamically generated content for the first time, I was struggling as well. Until I explored the website some more, and saw that they had a link where you could download the entire thing, tidied up, in a nice csv-format.
And for a webserver, people trying to scrape their website is often inconvenient, it also demands resources from the server, a lot more than someone downloading a file.
It's quite possible they'll tell you "no", but if they really don't want you to get their data, I bet they've made it difficult to scrape. Maybe you'll just get banned if you make too many requests from the same IP, maybe some other method.
And it's also entirely possible that they don't want their data in the hands of a competitor, but that they'll give it to you if you only use it for a particular purpose.

Answer (score 0):

(too big for a comment and it also has as salient image, but not an answer, per se)

Emil is spot on, except that this is a asp.net/sharepoint-esque site with binary "view states" and other really daft web practices that will make it nigh impossible to scrape with just `httr`:

[image]

When you do use the `Network` tab (again, as Emil astutely suggests) you can also use [`curlconverter`](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) to automatically build `httr` `VERB` functions out of requests "Copied as cURL".

For this site — assuming it's legal to scrape (it has no `robots.txt` and I am not fluent in Dutch and did not see an obvious "terms and conditions"-like link) — you can use something like [`splashr`](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) or Selenium to navigate, click and scrape since it acts like real browser.